# ARP headers out of sk_buff comes out all wrong(linux kernel module)

Tags: networking, kernel, c, arp

I am trying to pull ARP headers out of `skb` in `nfho` function. Here is my code:

```
int is_arp(struct sk_buff *skb) {
    struct arphdr *hdr = arp_hdr(skb);
    if(hdr->ar_pln != 4 || ar_hln != 6 || hdr->ar_hrd != ARPHRD_ETHER) {
        printk("%d   %d\n", pln, hln);
        return NOT_ARP;
        }
    return ARP_PACKET;
}
```

The function `arp_hdr()` is embedded in the kernel... and I am still getting wrong values compared to the fact that if I print the ip length (4 bytes... IPV4 of course) and hardware length (well... mac addresses 6 is a must) while sniffing with Wireshark some packets gets around my hook even though it shows wrong values......

Can anyone could tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function commits a logical fallacy informally known as "begging the question". The return value is supposed to indicate "is this ARP or not?"

But if you don't know whether that is true (since that is the proposition to be confirmed or refuted), how can you pull an ARP header out of the packet?

The `arp_hdr` function is just a wrapper around `skb_network_header` which casts the pointer to the arp header type.

Comment: that is the same way ARP validation is done in <linux/net/ipv4/arp.c> ...... if the packet is not under the terms of ARP protocol those values that are pointed will just happen to be corrupted. Or otherwise, how can you recognize if a packet is ARP packet when getting a packet as skb format ?

Comment: The ARP stack receives only frames which have the ETH_ARP ethertype, first of all.   (That doesn't mean they aren't garbage or truncated payloads.)